# Java method for android:layout_gravity

Tags: java, android, layout

I would like to know if is there a way to call `android:layout_gravity` property from a Java method. I didn't found any method in Android documentation to do it. This is the picture of the layout I want to implement:

http://www.anddev.org/resources/image/2234

I know to do it through XML, as following:

```
<FrameLayout
    xlmns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

      <Button
         android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:text="<" />


      <Button
         android:layout_gravity="right|center_vertical"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:text=">" />
</FrameLayout>
```

But in my situation, I need to do it through Java code, because I'll implement another layout views dynamically. To avoid merging XML layout with Java code, I would prefer make all layout using Java.

Comment: btw here it wouldn't be necessary to mark it community wiki ;)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Well as far as I understand you looking for [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/FrameLayout.LayoutParams.html#FrameLayout.LayoutParams%28int,%20int,%20int%29) It is for FrameLayout for other layout see appropriate LayoutParams classes. For setting gravity like in your XML use something like:

```
FrameLayout.LayoutParams params = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,Gravity.LEFT | Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL)
```

followed by `addView` with newly constructed `LayoutParams`

Comment: thre is no CENTRAL_VERTICAL, it should be [CENTER_VERTICAL](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Gravity.html)

Comment: And WRAP_CONTENT should be `ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT`

Comment: Someone correct me if I'm wrong, but doesn't this set the "gravity" of the object not the "layout gravity"?  I believe the OP is looking for "layout gravity"

Comment: @ BriCo84 : no, its layout gravity, because its `LayoutParams`

Answer (score 2):

Maybe I misunderstand you, but here it is:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setGravity(int)

Comment: Unfortunately that's the gravity for the text within the TextView, not the gravity for the layout of the TextView itself.

Comment: you can also use it for the button. the button inherits it

Comment: Yes, Steve. =( Unfortunately that's the gravity for the text, the same of android:gravity.

Answer (score 2):

Watchout! This wouldn't work with LinearLayout though. Because LinearLayout.LayoutParams(...)  constructor is different from FrameLayout.LayoutParams(...) constructor. The third parameter is not gravity but weight.

```
     LinearLayout.LayoutParams(int width, int height, float weight)
```

as opposed to

```
     FrameLayout.LayoutParams(int width, int height, int gravity)
```

and this call, despite **not producing** compiler error is actually wrong:

```
lparams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, Gravity.LEFT);
```

Comment: Although you cant set the gravity via the constructor but the gravity field of the LinearLayout.LayoutParams is public so you can use the gravity  from there

Answer (score 1):

```
button.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.sound_on);
        button.setText("On");
        button.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL| Gravity.RIGHT);
        button.invalidate();
```

Comment: layout_gravity is not the same thing as gravity. Gravity is the gravity of your children. Layout gravity is you telling your parent layout what you want your gravity to be.

Answer (score 1):

To change the `layout_gravity` attribute for an existing view:

```
Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.some_button);
FrameLayout.LayoutParams params;
params = (LayoutParams) button.getLayoutParams();

params.gravity = Gravity.BOTTOM | Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL;
button.setLayoutParams(params);
```

The button is contained in a `FrameLayout` which has a `gravity` attribute corresponding to the `layout_gravity` XML attribute. [Documentation link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/FrameLayout.LayoutParams.html#gravity).

Answer (score -2):

before adding the button, you should change the orientation of your layout

```
yourbutton.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);
LayoutParams layout = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, Gravity.RIGHT);
layout.gravity = Gravity.RIGHT;
yourbutton.setLayoutParams(layout);


yourlayout.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);
yourlayout.addView(yourbutton);
```

Comment: how does this answer the question?