# android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" in Java code

Tags: android

I have added a Button to a view in java code.  Basically I want to add the xml

```
android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
```

to the Button but do this in Java code, how is this done?

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2945315/java-method-for-androidlayout-gravity

Comment: That is for a FrameLayout and I already tired it before posting, it does not work.

Comment: Incedendly this is what I tried:   myButton.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL));

Comment: Update the question instead of posting ckde in comments

Answer (score 3):

use following method on your layout or on any view.

```
layout.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams
        ( (int) LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, (int) LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

params.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);

button.setLayoutParams(params);
```