# Setting Textview's Attributes Programmatically

Tags: android, textview, android-layout

I have created 5 TextView programmatically, now i want to set few Parameters/Attributes of their such as Gravity, Layout_Gravity, etc.

I know we can set it in XML layout at Design-time:

```
android:gravity="center|center_horizontal|center_vertical"
android:layout_gravity="center|center_horizontal|center_vertical"
```

But, How can we set Gravity/Layout_Gravity kinds of Attributes **programmatically**?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set the [gravity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setGravity(int) of TextView programmatically using `setGravity(int)`)

Probably you can set `layout_gravity` like this(I've not yet tested this) :

TextView can let its parent know about layout preferences using

```
setLayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams params)
LayoutParams params=new LayoutParams(this, attrSet);
tv.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Comment: Adding to what suresh has said i don't see a direct method to set layout_gravity programmatically. You could see android:layout_gravity doesn't have any direct java related methods in documentation where as android:gravity has one http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.LayoutParams.html

Comment: Layout gravity is for ViewGroup but TextView is not ViewGroup, is it right to set layout_gravity for it.?

Comment: The textview might be inside a viewgroup. We do not have the layout posted here... Anyhow framelayout can accept gravity in layout params... You can check if that helps you. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/FrameLayout.LayoutParams.html#FrameLayout.LayoutParams%28int,%20int,%20int%29  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2945315/java-method-for-androidlayout-gravity

Comment: Probably you can use setLayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams params) to set the layout_gravity.

Comment: Well that depends on the layout that is being used. LinearLayout and RelativeLayout cannot accept gravity to be passed on setLayoutParams where as FrameLayout can as per the docs http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.html#RelativeLayout.LayoutParams%28android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams%29 http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.LayoutParams.html#LinearLayout.LayoutParams%28int,%20int,%20float%29

Answer (score 0):

It's all in the docs. Look at the [documentation for View](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html), for example, under "XML Attributes". You'll see all XML attributes, and the corresponding method you'll need to call in code to get the same effect.