# How to change layout_gravity in ConstraintLayout programmatically?

Tags: java, android, android-constraintlayout, layout-gravity

I got an XML file that includes a ConstraintLayout and inside this layout i got three views.
The layout as its width set to "wrap_content" which automatically wrap it to the left side like this:

[image]

**in the XML edit window, when i set layout_gravity to the right, it moves the layout to the right as expected:**

[image]

**I'm trying to achieve the same layout_gravity movement to right but programmatically (in Java) but i can not find any way to do it.**

Comment: the wrap_content may cause the issue. try match_parent or some fix size (bigger than child views) to test.

Comment: What is your requirement? Please specify what all views do you need to display and be specific about there placement as well.

Comment: If I understand correctly, this answer might work for you: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2945763/11783376)

Comment: @mushter i tried it but it doesn't work because ConstraintLayout doesn't take a 3rd int argument like FrameLayout.

Comment: @NadeemShaikh I got a listview with this constraint layout for the items.
i want some items to show on the right side of the listview while keeping others on the left, like in the snapshots i put here

Comment: did you find a solution?

Comment: actually i did. i had to put this constraintview in another constraintview. than i was able to make the change.

Comment: You can check out this answer for any help.
[Setting constraints programatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45263159/constraintlayout-change-constraints-programmatically)